# Problems with negative lookahead shotcircuiting (REGEX) - Finding faulty formated strings

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

EDITED TO MAKE QUESTION MORE CLEAR

I've came up with the following regex to help me find expressions on the form `>(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\-\d{4}:\d+(,\d{1,2})?<`, what i want to do now is find out if my text contains similar expressions that are ill-formated, that is expressions that fits the first part of the regex (before the colon) but doesn't follow the number format specifed e.g. matching `>01-2018:a<`,`>01-2018:12,<` or `>01-2018:12,111<`

I've tried the following using negative lookahead `>(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\-\d{4}:(?!\d+(,\d{1,2})?).*<`

The problem with my solution is of course that it'll shortcircuit so to speak, which will give me a negative match on ie. `>01-2018:12,<` because it matches the "12" part. I'm unsure how to proceed.

Comment: Could you please explain the original issue? With the whole original pattern? This "shortened" description is not quite clear. Your current pattern is a bit too redundant (you can easily do without a lookahead).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Sure thing, it's done

Comment: Ok, what is wrong with `\b(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-\d{4}:(?!\d)` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/VItLEw/1))?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that it wouldn't match "01-2018:1," and even "01-2018:1a" even though they are both clearly wrong

Comment: Do you mean you want something like `\b(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-\d{4}:(?!\d*\.?\d+$)` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/VItLEw/2))? No number (int or float) after `:` and till the end of the string is allowed?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Something like it, but not entirely, besides swtiching "\." with "," and restricting the the decimals to 1 or 2, and substituting "*" with "+" for the first "\d", there is a problem with your solution requiring the pattern to be at the end of the string, which it wont necessarily be

Comment: That does not help. Please explain the exact requirements for the pattern you need to *match* after `:`.

Comment: I want to match everything that is not (an integer or an integer followed my a comma and one or two digits)

Comment: Then just `\b(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-\d{4}:(?!.*\d)` should do. See https://regex101.com/r/VItLEw/3.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that wouldn't work, for instance it doesn't match "01-2018:0," which is wrong, the problem here has of course something to do with delimeters, in my case i found out that i instead will be using ">" and "<" as start and end delimters respectively, but even applying these your solution won't work

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I want to match everything that is on the form `>((0[1-9])|(1[0-2]))\-\d{4}:.*<` but is not `>((0[1-9])|(1[0-2]))\-\d{4}:\d+(,\d{1,2})?<`

Comment: Like `>(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])-\d{4}:(?!\d+(?:,\d{1,2})?<)[^<]*<` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/VItLEw/4))?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That is exactly it, thank you for your patience. Make an answer, so i can accept it, and i will edit the original text to fit accordingly

Comment: Added an answer with explanations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
/>(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])-\d{4}:(?!\d+(?:,\d{1,2})?<)[^<]*</
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VItLEw/4)

**Details**

- `>` - a `>` char
- `(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])` - a month number, `01` to `12`
- `-` - a hyphen (no need escaping it)
- `\d{4}` - any 4 digits
- `:` - a colon
- `(?!\d+(?:,\d{1,2})?<)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if, immediately to the right of the current location, there is no

  - `\d+` - 1 or more digits
  - `(?:,\d{1,2})?` - an optional non-capturing group matching 1 or 0 occurrences of `,` followed with 1 or 2 digits
  - `<` - a `<` char
- `[^<]*` - important! - this consumes any 0+ chars other than `<` to get to the first...
- `<` - `<` char.